# All ways to partition a string

Tags: set, subset, partition

I'm trying to find a efficient algorithm to get all ways to partition a string

eg for a given string 'abcd' =>
'a' 'bcd'
'a' 'b' 'cd'
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
'ab' 'cd'
'ab' 'c' 'd'
'abc' 'd'
'a', 'bc', 'd

any language would be appreciated

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Efficient in terms of how quick and easy it is to code or in terms of how fast it runs?  Also is there a maximum length of the string?  It will give exponentially larger numbers of results as the string length grows and you'll hit out of memory errors fairly quickly.

Comment: Ii aim to input single words to this algo, and I would like it to be efficient in matter of speed, but I'm curious to see the two different approach :)

Comment: Not listing 'abcd' by itself might be by design, but I think that you missed  'a', 'bc', 'd'.

Comment: yes you're wright thx !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Problem analysis**

Between each pair of adjacent characters, you can decide whether to cut. For a string of size **n**, there are **n-1** positions where you can cut or not, i.e. there are two possibilities. Therefore a string of size **n** can be partitioned in **2<sup>n-1</sup>** ways.

The output consists of **2<sup>n-1</sup>** partitions, each having **n** characters plus separators. So we can describe the output size as **f(n) = 2<sup>n-1</sup> * n + s(n)** where **s(n) ≥ 0** accounts for the partition separators and line separators.

So due to the output size alone, an algorithm solving this problem must have exponential runtime or worse: **Ω(2<sup>n</sup>)**.

(**0 ≤ c * 2<sup>n</sup> = ½ * 2<sup>n</sup> = 2<sup>n-1</sup> ≤ 2<sup>n-1</sup> * n ≤ f(n)** for all **n≥k** with positive constants **c=½, k=1**)

---

**Solution**

I chose to represent a partition as integer. Each bit in `cutpoints` determines whether to cut between characters `i` and `i+1`. To iterate through all possible partitions, we just need to go trough all integers between `0` and `2^(n-1) - 1`.

Example: For a string of length 4, we go through all integers between `0` and `2^3 - 1` or `0` and `7` or in binary: `000` and `111`.

```python
# (python 2 or 3)
def all_partitions(string):
    for cutpoints in range(1 << (len(string)-1)):
        result = []
        lastcut = 0
        for i in range(len(string)-1):
            if (1<<i) & cutpoints != 0:
                result.append(string[lastcut:(i+1)])
                lastcut = i+1
        result.append(string[lastcut:])
        yield result

for partition in all_partitions("abcd"):
    print(partition)
```

**Memory usage:**

I think my solution uses `O(n)` memory with Python 3. Only one partition is generated at a time, it's printed and not referenced anymore. This changes of course, if you keep all results, e.g. by storing them in a list.

In Python 2 replace `range` with `xrange`, otherwise all possible `cutpoints` will be stored in a list, therefore needing an exponential amount of memory.

---

**JavaScript solution**

```js
// ES6 generator
function* all_partitions(string) {
    for (var cutpoints = 0; cutpoints < (1 << (string.length - 1)); cutpoints++) {
        var result = [];
        var lastcut = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < string.length - 1; i++) {
            if (((1 << i) & cutpoints) !== 0) {
                result.push(string.slice(lastcut, i + 1));
                lastcut = i + 1;
            }
        }
        result.push(string.slice(lastcut));
        yield result;
    }
}

for (var partition of all_partitions("abcd")) {
    console.log(partition);
}
```

Tested with NodeJS v4.4.3 (disclaimer: I have not used NodeJS before).

Comment: I tried to port this is javascript :
function* all_partitions(string) {
    var result, lastcut, i, cutpoints;
    for (cutpoints = 0; cutpoints < 1 << string.length - 1; cutpoints++) {
        result = [];
        lastcut = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < string.length - 1; i++) {
            if (1 << i & cutpoints !== 0) {
                result.push(string.slice(lastcut, i + 1));
                lastcut = i + 1;
            }
        }
        result.push(string.slice(lastcut));
        yield result;
    }
}
all_partitions("abcd"); without the same result, do you see what I could have missed ?

Comment: @Ben: I think you have a problem with operator precedence and need to use more parenthesis. I'll update my answer with a JS solution...

Comment: @johnLate how did you replace O(2^(n-1)*n) by O(2^n) ? Is not the latter bounded by the former for n > 2?

Comment: @arjunkhera You're right, I was sloppy when doing the simplification. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @arjunkhera I've thought about it some more and switched to Big-Omega instead of Big-O in the problem analysis since we are interested in a lower bound instead of an upper bound at this point.

Answer (score 3):

GeeksforGeeks has provided a well-explained solution to this problem:

For string `abcd` there will be 2^(n-1) i.e. 8 partitions.

```
(a)(b)(c)(d)
(a)(b)(cd)
(a)(bc)(d)
(a)(bcd)
(ab)(c)(d)
(ab)(cd)
(abc)(d)
(abcd)
```

The crux of the solution lies in the `recursion` to print all the permutations.
maintain two parameters – index of the next character to be processed and the output string so far. We start from index of next character to be processed, append substring formed by unprocessed string to the output string and recurse on remaining string until we process the whole string.

```
// Java program to find all combinations of Non-
// overlapping substrings formed from given
// string

class GFG 
{
    // find all combinations of non-overlapping
    // substrings formed by input string str
    static void findCombinations(String str, int index,
                                 String out)
    {
        if (index == str.length())
            System.out.println(out);

        for (int i = index; i < str.length(); i++)

            // append substring formed by str[index,
            // i] to output string
            findCombinations(str, i + 1, out +
                "(" + str.substring(index, i+1) + ")" );
    }

    // driver program
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        // input string
        String str = "abcd";
        findCombinations(str, 0, "");
    }
}
```

Time Complexity is O(2^n)

Here's the link to the article: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-ways-break-string-bracket-form/

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution which minimizes developer time by taking advantage of a built-in iterator. It should be reasonably quick for problem sizes for which the answer itself is not infeasibly large.

There is a one-to-one correspondence between partitions of a string and subsets of potential cutpoints. If the length of the string is `n` then there are `n-1` places where you could cut the string. A straightforward way would be to iterate through such subsets, and for each such subset, slice the string in that way. Here is a Python approach which uses the standard modules `itertools`:

```
import itertools

def multiSlice(s,cutpoints):
    k = len(cutpoints)
    if k == 0:
        return [s]
    else:
        multislices = [s[:cutpoints[0]]]
        multislices.extend(s[cutpoints[i]:cutpoints[i+1]] for i in range(k-1))
        multislices.append(s[cutpoints[k-1]:])
        return multislices

def allPartitions(s):
    n = len(s)
    cuts = list(range(1,n))
    for k in range(n):
        for cutpoints in itertools.combinations(cuts,k):
            yield multiSlice(s,cutpoints)
```

For example:

```
>>> parts = allPartitions('World')
>>> for p in parts: print(p)

['World']
['W', 'orld']
['Wo', 'rld']
['Wor', 'ld']
['Worl', 'd']
['W', 'o', 'rld']
['W', 'or', 'ld']
['W', 'orl', 'd']
['Wo', 'r', 'ld']
['Wo', 'rl', 'd']
['Wor', 'l', 'd']
['W', 'o', 'r', 'ld']
['W', 'o', 'rl', 'd']
['W', 'or', 'l', 'd']
['Wo', 'r', 'l', 'd']
['W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Note that this approach produces generates `['World']` as a partition of `'World'`. This corresponds to slicing with an empty set of cut points. I regard that as a feature rather than a bug since the standard mathematical definition of partition allows for a partition of a set into one piece. If this in undesirable for your purposes, the fix is easy enough -- just iterate over the nonempty subsets of the cut points. In terms of the above code, this fix amounts to adding two characters to `allPartitions`: replace

```
for k in range(n):
```

by

```
for k in range(1,n):
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to post a simple recursive solution to this problem for anyone stumbling on this question. Probably not the best way, but this was way simpler for me to understand and implement. If I am wrong, please correct me.

```py
def party(s:str, P:list, res:list) -> None :
    """Recursively generates all partitions of a given string"""
    res.append(P+[s])
    for i in range(1,len(s)):
        party(s[i:],P+[s[:i]],res)

res = []
party("abcd",[],res)
print(res)
"""
[['abcd'], ['a', 'bcd'], ['a', 'b', 'cd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
['a', 'bc', 'd'], ['ab', 'cd'], ['ab', 'c', 'd'], ['abc', 'd']]
"""
```

It works as follows:
Given a string or a substring of it, we can split after each of its character creating two halves.
Say: "abc" can be partitioned into ["a","bc"], ["ab","c"]

We save the first part in a intermediate partition `P` and
recursively call `party` on the other half.

Because both halves together form a complete partition we save it to `res`.
Example:

initially: s = "abc" is a valid partition, save it to res.

recr call: s = "bc", P = ["a"] , so P +[s]= ["a","bc"] is also valid, save it to `res`.

Proceed with splitting "bc".
P = ["a","b"], s="c" so P + [s] is also valid. And so on..

recr call 3: s = "c", P = ["ab"], so P + [s] =["ab","c"] is also valid, save it to `res`

Working:

```py
tests = ["abc","abcd","a"]
for t in tests:
    res = []
    party(t,[],res)
    print(f'{t} -> {res} \n')

"""Output
abc -> [['abc'], ['a', 'bc'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['ab', 'c']] 

abcd -> [['abcd'], ['a', 'bcd'], ['a', 'b', 'cd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
['a', 'bc', 'd'], ['ab', 'cd'], ['ab', 'c', 'd'], ['abc', 'd']] 

a -> [['a']] 
"""
```

Comment: I found this much easier to understand than the bit shifting one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly standard depth first search (backtracking) problem.

```cpp
void dfs(int startIndex, const string& s, vector<string>& tmp, 
vector<vector<string>>& res){
  if (startIndex == s.size()) {
    res.push_back(tmp);
    return;
  }
  
  for (int i = 1; startIndex + i <= s.size(); ++i) {
    tmp.push_back(s.substr(startIndex, i));
    dfs(startIndex + i, s, tmp, res);
    tmp.pop_back();
  }
}

int main()
{
  vector<vector<string>> res;
  vector<string> tmp;
  string s = "abcd";
  dfs(0, s, tmp, res);
}
```

For its execution and result please refer to [here](https://onlinegdb.com/XcBqdge-H).

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the following (untested and likely buggy VB.NET sample)

```
Function FindAllGroups(s As String) As List(Of List(Of String))
    Dim ret As New List(Of List(Of String))
    Dim l As New List(Of String)
    l.Add(s) 'the whole string unbroken
    ret.Add(l) 'first option we return is the whole unbroken string by itself
    If s.Length > 1 Then
        Dim tmp = FindAllGroups(s.Substring(1)) 'find all the groups for the rest of the string after the first character
        For Each l2 in tmp
            l = l2.ToList 'Copy it
            l.Insert(s.SubString(0,1),0)'insert the first character from this string by itself before this combination for the rest of the string
            ret.Add(l)
        Next
        For Each l2 in tmp
            l = l2.ToList 'Copy it
            l(0)= s.SubString(0,1) & l(0) 'insert the first character from this string as part of the first element in the list
            ret.Add(l)
        Next
   End If
   Return ret
End Function
```

This basically works by saying that we can take 'abcd' and split it into

```
'a', 1st option for 'bcd' split
'a', 2nd option for 'bcd' split
...
+
1st option for 'bcd' split with the first element prepended with 'a'
2nd option for 'bcd' split with the first element prepended with 'a'
...
```

then to calculate 'bcd', we just repeat the process as above, only with

```
'b', 1st option for 'cd' split
'b', 2nd option for 'cd' split
...
+
1st option for 'cd' split with the first element prepended with 'b'
2nd option for 'cd' split with the first element prepended with 'b'
...
```

etc. repeated recursively.

However, this code isn't particularly efficient at runtime.  One thing that you could do to speed it up significantly would be to add a Dictionary(Of String, List(Of List(Of String)) outside the function which you can store a cache of the results in and if the item exists in there, you return from there, if not, calculate it and add it.  Lists also might not be the most efficient, and the ToList function might not be the quickest way of cloning.  However, I've simplified it to make it easier to understand and also to save me time working it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<string> ans;
string s;

void solve(int previouscut, int len)
{
    if(previouscut == s.length()) // base case
    {
        for(auto str:ans)
            cout << str << " " ;
        cout << "\n";
        return;
    }
    
    if(previouscut+len>s.length()) // boundary case
        return;
    
    //cut
    ans.push_back(s.substr(previouscut,len));
    solve(previouscut + len,1);
    ans.pop_back();   //backtrack

    // no cut
    solve(previouscut, len+1);
}

int main()
{   
    cin >> s;
    solve(0,1);
    return 0;
}
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/substring-in-cpp/#

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
#use dfs 

def partition(s):
    result = []
    n = len(s)
    
    def dfs(st, so_far):
        if st == n:
            result.append(so_far)
            return
    
        for i in range(st, n):
            dfs(i+1, so_far + [s[st:i+1]])

    dfs(0, [])
    return result
    
    
print(partition('abcd'))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?